# update dom element electron

Tags: dom, electron

I'm trying to update an element in an electron app and I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work

```
         let timeStatus = document.getElementById('identifier');
         timeStatus = 'new time';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here is replacing the entire DOM node with string value "new time".
What you actually need to do is this.

```
let timeStatus = document.getElementById('identifier');
timeStatus.innerHTML = 'new time';
```

where innerHTML is the property of HTMLElement returned by document.getElementById()